# Tensorflow not detecting GPU after installing prerequisites

Tags: tensorflow, anaconda, gpu, nvidia

I went into Anaconda Prompt and did the following:

```
conda create --name tf-gpu
conda activate tf-gpu
conda install python=3.10
conda install cudatoolkit=11.2 -c anaconda -c conda-forge
conda install pip
pip install tensorflow-gpu==2.10.0
```

After this, when testing for GPU with

```
import tensorflow as tf
print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')))
```

I get: `Num GPUs Available:  0`

Why is it it not detecting my GPUs? I have two: NVIDIA RTX A5000 and NVIDIA T400

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you haven't install [cuDNN](https://developer.nvidia.com/cudnn). Install it too, using:

`conda install -c conda-forge cudatoolkit=11.2 cudnn=8.1.0`

It is clearly stated on the [tf requirements page](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#windows-native)